# How to store SKShapeNode to system defaults using NSUserDefault

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, nsuserdefaults, skscene, skshapenode

Now I am working on an app based on `SKScene`. And I want to store some `SKShapeNode` to system defaults so user can still see them when reopening the app after it is totally closed. I store the `SKShapeNodes` in a `NSMutableDictionary`. I tried to store it to `NSUserDefault` using `setObjectForKey` but it gave me the error:

`Property list invalid for format: 200 (property lists cannot contain objects of type 'CFType')`.

Because I am trying to add `SKShapeNode` to it. So how can I store it like the way of `NSUserDefault`? Thanks so much!!

Here is my code: 
    myNode = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithCircleOfRadius:radius];
    [myNode setPhysicsBody:[SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:radius]];
    myNode.fillColor = [uicolor greenColor];
    myNode.lineWidth = 1.0;
    [myNode setPosition:positionInScene1];
    myNode.antialiased = YES;
    myNode.glowWidth = 0.0;
    myNode.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
    myNode.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    myNode.physicsBody.restitution = 0.3; 
    [mainLists myNode forKey:someKey];(mainList is a nsdictionary) 
    NSUserDefault *store = [NSUserDefault standardDefault]; 
    [store setObject:mainList forKey:@"mainList"]; 
    [store sychronize];

Comment: Are there any other ways to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
[NSKeyedArchiver -archivedDataWithRootObject:]
```

first you serializable object to the NSData, then save data to the userDefault.

When you want to read the data, you should decode the data to the SKShapeNode using NSKeyedUnarchiver

You can learn from [NSKeyedArchiver/NSKeyedUnarchiver](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/)  
Or you can only save the property of the node

Comment: Can you explain more in specific way? I haven't used that before. If I create one like SKShapeNode *node = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithCircleOfRadius:radius]; and I set many properties of it like mass, physicsBody, lineWith, color. So how can I store it and load it using the way you provided?

Comment: I have figured out! Thanks a lot!